# Не понятная ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
List = []
while True:
    a = input("Pleas enter a number or click <Enter> to start: " )
    List += int(a)
except ValueError as err:
    n = 0
    for b in range(List):
        ma_x = b
        mi_n = b
        if b >= ma_x:
        ma_x = b
        if b <= mi_n:
            mi_n = b
        Sum += b
        n += 1
    print("cout = ", n, " sum = ", Sum, " lowest = ", mi_n, "higest = ", ma_x, "mean = ", Sum/n)
```

В пятой строке выдаёт ошибку:

```
D:\Programs\learning program>calculator.py
  File "D:\Programs\learning program\Calculator.py", line 5
except ValueError as err:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Хотя строчку написал вроде правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try: # !!!
    while True:
        a = input("Pleas enter a number or click <Enter> to start: " )
        List += int(a)
except ValueError as err:
    n = 0
    ...
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Без try: Обработчик иключений не работает что ли?

Comment: @Бронеслав совершенно верно